# problems installing multiple versions of perl including latest

Tags: perl, installation

I have perl 5.8.8 installed in /usr/bin/perl

I need to use a later version, so am trying to install another version in a different place.
(nb. I started out trying to install perlbrew but on the linux server I'm using but that's not working - am getting all sorts of certificate problems).

I logged in as root and followed the instructions here, to install perl from source:

http://www.cpan.org/src/

This gave me an install of perl in

```
/root/localperl/bin/perl
```

I thought that didn't look right so I copied that the localperl directory to /usr

```
cp -r localperl/ /usr/
```

Now I can run a script in my /home/myusername/ directory by using

```
/usr/localperl/bin/perl
```

So I guess that looks more normal for an alternate install of perl, though:

a) Am not sure this is correct.  So the question is if I stick #!/usr/localperl/bin/perl as the first line in every script, will all be fine?

b) Have no idea what to do to install modules for this new version.  So:

i)   What to do to build latest versions of modules for this version?
ii)  Can I copy across all my existing modules that work with 5.8.8?

(Yes, I did attempt to read the doc and saw there were lots of options for configuring the install, but having tried one or two found this was even more confusing).  Any specific help on the above appreciated.

Comment: Usually you do a configure --prefix=/whatever/your/path/is and then make install. But the easiest way is perlbrew and you can just get the perl-version.tgz from somewhere (no certificate problems) and then do a perlbrew install perl-version.tgz.

Comment: perlbrew doesn't install on the linux server I am using due to certificate problems when following the instructions here: http://perlbrew.pl/ . So apparently not easy.  From the starting point in the question (ie. perl installed in /usr/localperl/bin/perl), do you know how to proceed with using that perl (seems to work ok from the limited scripts I've tried it on) and install modules that work with it?

Comment: if the perl is build with /usr/localperl/bin (unusual, default is /usr/local/bin) and correctly installed using 'make install' you can just use it as /usr/localperl/bin/perl and install modules with /usr/localperl/bin/cpan. But this only works if it was installed in the path it was build for (e.g. given during configure).

Comment: ok - I just accepted the defaults from the source install process described in the question.  So thanks, I see cpan is found in that directory.  Question:  I have loads of modules installed in my 5.8.8 build - how do I "copy" them across for use with 5.18?

Comment: You might try to just use them by setting PERL5LIB (but make sure that new perl path comes first, see perl -V for default include path). But if these modules were build using XS (e.g. modules depending on C libraries, like openssl, ...) you might need to rebuild them because they were build against the older perl.

Comment: +1 for Steffen's comment about perl only running if you leave it where it was first installed.  There is a 'relocate perl' command somewhere, but I don't recommend it.  Use it where you first installed it, or just reinstall it.